# how to avoid TABLE ACCESS FULL when fetching rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 18c but I guess my question would not be bound to the specific version.
I want to fetch rows from a table but I found a complex, ugly solution.
I would like to know if there is better, simple query that can return the same result as following.

First of all, I have a simple table like this.
Note that col is going to store large text.

```
CREATE TABLE simpletable
 (record_id NUMBER,
 col CLOB,
 PRIMARY KEY (record_id));
```

I want to retrieve single row from the above table and whichever row is acceptable.
First query came to my mind is as following.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM simpletable) WHERE rownum <= 1;
```

Another is as following.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM simpletableORDER BY record_id) WHERE rownum <= 1;
```

Unfortunately, neither of above two does not use primary-key index and uses `TABLE ACCESS FULL` which can take long time when the table grows enough large.
(I'm guessing that oracle preferred the simpler plan because my table is not enough large yet to use index scan.
Oracle might choose different plan if the table grows up further.)

My final solution that uses primary-key index to narrow down the table access is following.

```
SELECT simpletable.* FROM
 (SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT record_id, ROWID as id FROM simpletable ORDER BY record_id)
  WHERE rownum<=1) a
JOIN simpletable ON a.id = simpletable.ROWID;
```

If you have a better solution, please let me know.
It would be very appreciated.

P.S.
The first two queries produced the following plan.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |                |     1 |  2015 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY          |                |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                  |                |     1 |  2015 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|                |     1 |  2015 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | SIMPLETABLE    |     1 |  2015 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the final one is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                |     1 |  2039 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS               |                |     1 |  2039 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   VIEW                      |                |     1 |    25 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    COUNT STOPKEY            |                |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     VIEW                    |                |     1 |    25 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      INDEX FULL SCAN        | SYS_C007561    |     1 |    25 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID| SIMPLETABLE    |     1 |  2014 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I would say ... don't do this. If it's not causing you problems, don't micro-optimize this sort of thing. It's literally the optimizer's job to select an appropriate plan for a table. You're almost certainly right that it's doing a full table scan because there aren't enough rows in the table to matter.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the [Horror Vacui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui), some database developers suffer under the Horror `FULL TABLE SCAN` by simply assuming *index access good, full scan bad*.

But this is not true, `FULL TABLE SCAN` is a *normal* access method, that is *preferred* in some situation.

Let's illustrate it on a simple example with 10K rows in your table

```
insert into simpletable (record_id, col)
select rownum, rpad('x',3998,'y')
from dual connect by level <= 10000
```

To get **one arbitrary row** from the table you simple use the following query

```
 select * from simpletable where rownum = 1;
```

Here is the output (edited for brevity) you get from SQL*Plus with setting `set autotrace traceonly` to see the execution plan and the statistics.

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1007892724

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |             |     1 |  2015 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |             |       |       |            |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| SIMPLETABLE | 10188 |    19M|     2   (0)| 00:00:01
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          5  consistent gets
          2  physical reads
          1  rows processed
```

The most important information is the statistics `consistent gets` - there were only `5`  blocks accessed - the table is much larger.

What is the explanation? See the  operation `COUNT STOPKEY` above the `TABLE ACCESS FULL` this ensures that the scan is *terminated* after the first row is found.

If you want to get a specific row, e.g. the one with the **highest ID**, the prefered approach is using the [row_limiting_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

```
SELECT *
FROM simpletable
ORDER BY record_id DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

You will see the execution plan below, that performs first the `INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING`. The complete (`full`) index will be red in the *descending* order, but again due to `STOPKEY` you break after reading the highest key (which is the first entry due to the `descending` order).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |             | 10188 |    19M|   613   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |             | 10188 |    19M|   613   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY       |             | 10188 |    19M|   613   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SIMPLETABLE | 10188 |    19M|   613   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| SYS_C008793 | 10188 |       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=CASE  WHEN (0>=0) THEN
              0 ELSE 0 END +1 AND "from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber">0)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY
              INTERNAL_FUNCTION("SIMPLETABLE"."RECORD_ID") DESC )<=CASE  WHEN (0>=0) THEN 0 ELSE 0
              END +1)
```

**Note** if the table is empty or contains very few rows, you will se even here a `TABLE ACCESS FULL` because the optimizer recognises that it is more effective that to first go to the index and that access the table.

Answer (score 1):

If the Cost Based Optimizer code has access to reliable statistics, from its dictionary, regarding all the objects available for this query, then it will very likely produce an optimal execution plan. Of course, there are exceptions and you would argue with their support people as to whether or not choosing a suboptimal plan is a bug.

In this specific case, if you are querying a single table and the CBO *could* choose between a full table scan and some other scan and then chose a full table scan, then chances were good that the CBO determined that the number of blocks scanned (buffer gets) would have been smaller using a full table scan.

You can expose the truth of the matter by tracing the execution of multiple versions of the statement, each one using a different set of hints to force a particular execution plan. You should consider the execution with the fewest buffer gets to be the winner. Alternatively, if the execution plan is of a serial nature, then you can use response time as measure. If the winner is not automatically chosen by the CBO, then it's probably because the statistics it used were not accurate and you should make them accurate. If the statistics are indeed accurate then Oracle support will probably give you a very long homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `OFFSET..FETCH` method might helps you here -

```
SELECT *
  FROM simpletable
 ORDER BY record_id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
 FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. unfortunately, your query produced a plan with `TABLE ACCESS FULL`.